# wait the end of an asynchronous http request for continue

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a chatview to take some data from an asynchronous request and show it to the user with a listview, but i can't figure it out a way for wait the end of my thread.

For example , my test() function is called before the end of the "try"

```
       ApiRestClient.get("chatroom/mines", requestparams, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, java.lang.String responseString) {
            try {
                JSONArray reader = new JSONArray(responseString);
                ChatRoomBDD.open();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = reader.getJSONObject(i);
                    String idroom = jsonobject.getString("id");
                    String match_id = jsonobject.getString("url");
                    newsData = new UserInfoChatRoom();
                    newsData.setMatch_id(match_id);
                    newsData.setIdRoom(idroom);
                    ChatRoomBDD.insertRoom(newsData);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, java.lang.String responseString, java.lang.Throwable throwable) {
            d("error", responseString + statusCode);
        }
    });
    test();
}

public void test()
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: That's the principle of "asynchronous": you can do something else while the request is sent in the background. If you want test() to be called once the response is available, the call to test() should be in the onSuccess() method.

Comment: this is not a question about `android-studio`, therefore i suggest we should delete the `android-studio` tag

Comment: Cant you make it an async class and use the onPostExecute() method?

Comment: Check documentation for ApiRestClient to see if there's synchronous GET method. That's the only way to stop executing because as @JBNizet mentioned - whole purpose of "asynchronous" is to do it in separate thread. Since Android is in question - it's possible that you have to do it async since android does not allow network communication in UI (main) thread. Not an android expert but that was the first issue I've stumbled upon when started learning Android.

Comment: You can make the test method a Runnable instead, and execute it inside of the onSuccess.